# Windows Universal App - Disable item in ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to set item disabled for ComboBox, I have my item model:

```
public class PermissionsViewItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

And ComboBox defined:

```
<ComboBox Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="65,308,0,0" BorderThickness="0" Width="220" Padding="0" Foreground="#FF7B7A7F" ItemsSource="{Binding PermissionsViewItems}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:PermissionsViewItem">
                <StackPanel >
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

However there seems to be no way to set item disabled manually, but there is ComboBoxItem element generated (I can see it in LiveVisualTree) which has IsEnabled property and it works. I can access it via Styling

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" >
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This would disable every item, but unfortunately ItemContainerStyle does not bind to item, because it has context of ComboBox not PermissionsViewItem so I cannot utilize PermissionsViewItem.IsEnabled property here.

Is there is any way to disable specific item (even a hacky way will suffice)?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the combobox as follows and set the bindings at run time. This works for me

```
public class ZCombobox:ComboBox
    {
        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            ComboBoxItem zitem = element as ComboBoxItem;

            if (zitem != null)
            {
                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelectable");
                zitem.SetBinding(ComboBoxItem.IsEnabledProperty, binding);
            }
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind IsEnabled property in TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" FontWeight="SemiBold" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
```

Comment: First - TextBlock does not have IsEnabled property. Second - of course I can mimic IsEnabled in DataTemplate, but selection and highlighting is still there which is provided by ComboBox control unless I set ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled = false somehow.

Comment: Sorry about that , i check IsEnabled on wpf project. On WinRT Textblock has Visibility property. Try bind this ?

Comment: Again - it wont help, it does not disable item. Visibility property is used for displaying item, I do not want to hide or remove item. Also disabling TextBlock or parent grid for that matter does not remove ComboBox highlighting and taping effects.